# How to discover all instances in the same ec2 security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Unfortunately it is not possible to use the gossip protocol as a node discovery mechanism on ec2.

So I need to find a way to list all private ip addresses of the nodes which are located in the same security group. I want to do this over an auto discovery mechanism.

**More details**:

I have multiple ec2 instances which are running all the same docker container but the docker container has no aws-cli installed. Therefore I am looking for a way to detect the other instances with an existing registry or at least without aws-cli as dependency. The application running in the container needs the ips of the other containers to connect to each other.

Comment: Have you considered using instance tagging to achieve this instead of security group membership?

Comment: No, how can I resolve from within an instance all instances with the same tag and their private ip?

Comment: You would just query for all instances, filtering on the tag.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I left some details and why I can't use aws-cli. Therefore I updated the question.

Comment: Then use one of the many AWS SDKs in the programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 5):

Use `describe-instances` with `filter` group-name or group-id.

From: [describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)

- instance.group-id - The ID of the security group for the instance.
- instance.group-name - The name of the security group for the instance.

Using Security Group ID

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance.group-id,Values=sg-082b1234" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]' --output text
```

Output

```
10.1.1.24
10.1.1.49
```

Using Security Group Name

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance.group-name,Values=default" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]' --output text
```

Output

```
10.1.1.24
10.1.1.49
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately I didn't tell the whole story and that I have no way to execute aws-cli from within the docker container.

Comment: As @MarkB suggested, use any of the SDKs. Either attach an IAM role to your instance or pass the credentials.

Answer (score -1):

The first method is to use the SDKs (e.g., AWS JAVA SDK) as @Markb, @helloV suggested.

The second method is to create another instance which could run aws-cli as helper instance (e.g, ip: 222.222.222.222), then you can execute the remote aws cli command in your docker instance to get the instance IPs

```
ssh centos@222.222.222.222 'YOUR_AWS_CLI_Command'
```