# List of instance which are attached to specific security group thru AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I need the list of instances which are attached to specific security group
 I tried below

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --group-name abc \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId], Tags[?Key==`Applications`].Value' \
  --output table
```

But its not giving me the output.

I need the following details:

- Application
- Application Owner
- App Owner
- Email
- Security Group ID
- Security Group Name
- Attached Instance
- Port 20 open to public

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to discover all instances in the same ec2 security group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098917/how-to-discover-all-instances-in-the-same-ec2-security-group)

Comment: See my answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098917/how-to-discover-all-instances-in-the-same-ec2-security-group

Comment: Are all this your tags which you want in output?